# How to initialize a logger of compass?

Tags: ruby, logging, compass-sass

I'm trying compass in irb, this is my code:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\test>irb

irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'compass'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> logger = Compass::Logger.new()
NameError: uninitialized constant Compass::Logger
        from E:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.10.6/lib/compass/versio
n.rb:51:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):3
irb(main):004:0>
```

But there is a `Logger` class in `compass/loggers.rb`:

```
module Compass
    class Logger
        DEFAULT_ACTIONS = [:directory, :exists, ...]
```

Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'compass/logger'   # <- note the path
=> true
irb(main):003:0> logger = Compass::Logger.new()
=> #<Compass::Logger:0x1011423f8 @actions=[:directory, :exists, :remove, :create, :overwrite, :compile, :error, :identical, :warning], @options={}>
```